# Discord JS Embed reaction to lead to another embed

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So I've tried numerous times to make a reaction from an embed to lead to another embed but i cannot figure out how to get it to work without some sort of error. Help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For your question to be answered, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-reactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of sending an embed and adding a [reaction collector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) which triggers a new embed to appear in the message.

```js
var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#FFFFFF')
  .setDescription('Test');

message.channel.send(embed)
  .then(m => {
    m.react('➡️');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡️' && user.id === message.author.id;
    const collector = m.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 5 * 60 * 1000 }); // 5 min

    collector.on('collect', () => {
      m.clearReactions();

      var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#007FFF')
        .setDescription('Test #2');

      m.edit(embed);
    });
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do it with more than one reactions to lead to different embeds?

Comment: Absolutely. You can have multiple collectors (named differently) and follow the same setup. If you need the reactions in order, make sure to declare the `then()` callback as [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and then you can use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).